# what is the difference in the nuances / usage of 気に病む and 心配する ?

Tags: usage, vocabulary, nuances, words, synonyms

I was wondering what is the difference in the nuances / usage of 気に病む and 心配する ?

(E.g. If I want to tell my friend not to worry about a test (albeit an important test), is it more appropriate to use 気に病むな　or 心配するな ?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's simply a difference of image just like "Don't worry" and "don't make yourself sick over it"

It depends on the level of anxiety of your friend (気に病むな being stronger)

Answer (score 1):

心配しないでね is the common saying, trying to get them from not worrying about it. I dont recall anyone ever saying 気に病まないで to me.

I would avoid using 心配するな because it is the command to "Dont worry!" as in "Dont touch or ill call the teacher!" kinda thing.